# Guess the number in python. Option to close game

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to Python and programming and i'm trying to make the "Guess the number" game. I made it work but i want the add the option to close the game using the **brake** statement. I've been trying for 2 days but i guess im stuck.

Here is the code that works (without the option to close the game) :

```
import random
attempts = 0
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
while True:
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 100")
    guess=input()
    guess = int(guess)
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if guess >100 or guess<=0:
        attempts = attempts - 1
        print("Not allowed.Only numbers between 1 and 100 allowed! \n")
    elif guess < secretNumber and guess >0:
        print("Nope!Try a higher number! \n")
    elif guess > secretNumber and guess <100:
        print("Nope!Try a lower number \n")
    if guess == secretNumber:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
            attempts = str(attempts)
print("Congratulations you found it after " + attempts + " attempts")
```

Code (with option to close the game) that doesnt work :

```
import random
attempts = 0
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
while True:
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 100. You can exit game anytime by typing quit ")
    stop=input()
    stop=str(stop)
    if stop == "quit":
        break
        print("You quitted the game")
    else:
            continue
    guess=input()
    guess = int(guess)
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if guess >100 or guess<=0:
        attempts = attempts - 1
        print("Not allowed.Only numbers between 1 and 100 allowed! \n")
    elif guess < secretNumber and guess >0:
        print("Nope!Try a higher number! \n")
    elif guess > secretNumber and guess <100:
        print("Nope!Try a lower number \n")
    if guess == secretNumber:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
            attempts = str(attempts)
print("Congratulations you found it after " + attempts + " attempts")
```

I'm sorry for the long post, any help on what i'm doing wrong or even a different approach to achieve this using the **break** statement and without using the def function will be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Remove your `else:continue`. `continue` makes the code continue at the beginning of the loop again.

Comment: And `print` before breaking out

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nick A and timgeb . I did both but its still not working. After entering a number  nothing happens, i have to type the number again to work, if i dont and just press enter again i get a ValueError and when i type quit, it works but i get a NameError..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few changes and all is good

```
import random
attempts = 0
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
while True:
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 100. You can exit game anytime by typing q ")
    guess=input()
    stop=str(guess)
    if stop== 'q':
        print("You quitted the game")
        break
    elif not guess.isdigit():
        print("Only numbers are allowed")
    else:        
        guess = int(guess)
        attempts = attempts + 1
        if guess >100 or guess<=0:
            attempts = attempts - 1
            print("Not allowed.Only numbers between 1 and 100 allowed! \n")
        elif guess < secretNumber and guess >0:
            print("Nope!Try a higher number! \n")
        elif guess > secretNumber and guess <100:
            print("Nope!Try a lower number \n")
        if guess == secretNumber:
            attempts = str(attempts)
            print("Congratulations you found it after " + attempts + " attempts")
            break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @legendisback !! Definitely a legend..It worked!

Comment: I've been trying to use the .isdigit() method to avoid getting a ValueError when user inputs str instead of int, i tried to change the "q" word to 0 to avoid conflicts with no luck..is this possible? Any thoughts??Thanks a lot for your time..

Comment: @Mike_R edited the program, now .isdigit() is added to allow only numbers for guessing

Comment: Amazing!Thank you very much once again!

Comment: The value from `input` will already be a string in Python 3, no need to convert it with `str()`

Answer (score 0):

Beneath what  Nick A and timgeb mentioned in their comments, you could adapt a few things.
As I suggest in the following script, you might want to have a look at [try and except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Please find comments inside the script.

```
import random
attempts = 0
secretNumber = random.randint(1,100)
# you can prompt the user within input()
stop=input("Guess a number between 1 and 100. You can exit game anytime by typing quit ")

while True:
    if stop == "quit": # as the the output of input() is a string, you can compare it with a string without str()
        print("You quitted the game")
        break
    try: # work with try and except to avoid problems whenever the user writes something else than 'quit' or an integer
        guess = int(stop)
        attempts += 1
        if guess >100 or guess<=0:
            attempts = attempts - 1
            print("Not allowed.Only numbers between 1 and 100 allowed! \n")
        elif guess < secretNumber and guess >0:
            print("Nope!Try a higher number! \n")
        elif guess > secretNumber and guess <=100: # note that it's <=. Otherwise nothing happens when the users chose 100
            print("Nope!Try a lower number \n")
    except: # if it's not possible to turn 'stop' into an integer we'd like to perform the following
        stop = input("No valid input, please guess again ") # Don't stop the script, let the user guess again
        continue # don't stop, but leave the current iteration (don't execute the rest) and start again at the beginning of the loop 
    if guess == secretNumber:
        attempts = str(attempts)
        print("Congratulations you found it after " + attempts + " attempts")
        break
    stop = input("Guess again ") # prompt for a new number every round of the loop
```

Comment: It works great, but i don't want the program to stop when user submits an invalid value, so i removed the "break" after the "except:" and the loop doesnt stop. The problem comes when the first submited value is invalid..i get a NameError. Any thoughts on how i could solve this? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: If you remove `break`, and the user submits an invalid input, `guess` is not defined, because it's not possible to turn the invalid input into an integer. What you basically could do is to change the respective `if` statement and work with `continue` instead of `break`. I updated the script and wrote comments how it works. You can learn more about the continue statement [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html). Feel free to ask any further question!